# Model seems to have no information with CompoundJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, compoundjs, jugglingdb

I'm using CompoundJS and MongoDB (juggling-mongodb). This is the code I have:

schema.js:

```
var User = describe('User', function() {
property('_id', Number, {
    index: true
});
property('name', String);
property('email', String);
property('password', String);

set('restPath', pathTo.users);
    setTableName('users');
});
```

database.js:

```
module.exports = 
 { "development":
    { "driver":   "mongodb",
      "url": "mongodb://admin:1234@localhost/didgeridoo"
    }
 , "test":
    { "driver":   "postgres"
    }
 , "production":
    { "driver":   "postgres"
    }
 };
```

and i'm doing:

```
User.all(function(err, result) {
    //but here result is always empty and there is no error
});
```

Also there is not a connection problem and collections have data ;)

Anybody knows what can it be?

Thanks!

Comment: add your answer in the answers section below!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering the same, you must know that setTableName() method is not yet implemented for all the ORM's as the time of this writing. Hope it helps!